# Apache Camel Jetty Multipart: load text file with non-Latin charset or binary file

Tags: apache-camel, embedded-jetty

Camel 2.24.0

I am struggling to load a simple csv file that is not in a Latin charset, from a web form with file field:

```
<form action="/register/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="inputfile"/>
<input type="submit"/>
```

Here's my current endpoint URL:

```
jetty:http://0.0.0.0:{{web.port}}/register/upload?httpMethodRestrict=POST
```

What happens is that the contents of the file is converted into String with multiple black question marks in place of non-Latin characters.

When I try to load a binary file like jpeg, it still puts the file contents as an ugly String into headers of the HttpMessage.

I can't see where I am asking to convert my file into String, but for a text (csv) file that would be okay if only it was able to use some charset other than the Latin-1.

I have read a lot of articles everywhere and have tried different magic to no avail. What I remember is a url query parameter to switch on/off the Multipart Filter, and in the web form  to add a hidden `_charset_` field.

The [Apache Jetty Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jetty-component.html) says that the Multi-part should work out of the box and even mentions some example, but unfortunately there is no hyperlink. Anyway, the HttpMessage attachments are empty, so it doesn't actually work as advertized.

So the question in simple terms is "how do I specify my endpoint URL so that I am able to get non-corrupt file contents that was uploaded through a web form, and how do I get the file contents". Or maybe, "do I have to add some attribute to the web form"

Comment: What is the charset / encoding you are expecting it to be?  Since you didn't mention one, the default is likely loaded with UTF-8.

Comment: It's windows 1251, a one byte encoding for Russian letters

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things to consider.

- Are all POST requests via that form going to be Windows-1251?
- Does the HTML charset that the form was presented on matter to you?
- Do you want the user to pick the charset?

You mentioned the "hidden charset field".  It's actually called `_charset_` (with the start and end underscores present), and it's important to understand how it works with HTML forms.

That works by creating a hidden field in your form like this ...

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/formsubmit">
    <input type="hidden" name="_charset_"/>
    <p>Japanese</p>
    <input type="text" name="japanese" value="健治"/>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <input type="text" name="hello" value="ャユ戆タ"/>
    <p></p>
    <input type="Submit" value="Capture">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, that's an incomplete example.

Why?  Well, that will submit via the `_charset_` form entry whatever the browser's HTML document charset is.  Which in the above example could be darn near anything and is unpredictable.

You could specify the Document charset as a meta entry, like this ...

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form ...>
```

That will present the HTML in utf-8 **and** submit the form where the `_charset_` entry is value `utf-8`.  (It also makes anything hand-typed into text fields on your form be UTF-8)

But wait, what if you wanted to have the form be a different charset?

You could do the following ...

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form accept-charset="windows-1251"
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/formsubmit">
    <input type="hidden" name="_charset_"/>
    ...
```

That will declare that all form submissions are `windows-1251`, and this is done by also submitting the `_charset_` entry with the value `windows-1251`.

But this means your form submissions will be `windows-1251`, which might not be feasible for some submissions.

You also mentioned that you are doing CSV form uploads.

You might want to consider doing a form file upload instead (as that will not interpret via the `_charset_` or encoding types).

```html
<form method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/formupload">
    <p>File</p>
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="Submit" value="Capture">
</form>
```

This all assumes that Apache Camel uses the [`HttpServletRequest.getParts()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts--) 
 (and equivalent) APIs, and not something custom. (like the ancient Apache FileUpload lib).

The way the API works is that all parts of a multipart are binary and have no encoding or charset associated with them UNTIL you attempt to access it.

For `<input>` entries, no charset is applied via the Servlet [`Part`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) API.

However, if Apache Camel uses `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()` style APIs, then the `_charset_` is applied to the binary data held by the multipart section when returning the String.

Equivalent to ...

```java
String charset = getPart("_charset_");
if(charset == null)
    charset = "utf-8"
try(InputStream in = getPart(keyname).getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.forName(charset));
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
    IO.copy(reader, writer);
    return writer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so my question is how to instruct Camel not to convert the part to a String, which it seemingly does. And by the way, as I have mentioned in my question, providing the `_charset_` hidden field didn't help. (Underscores were interpreted as italic style by SO, I am fixing it now)